# Why is st_intersects giving bad results?

Tags: postgis

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.2.2 with PostGIS 2.0.2 (or just 2.0, not sure), and need to do simple queries to find points that intersect with a polygon.

The following test case returns only partial results for an unknown reason.  If the minimum longitude value of the polygon is changed from 0 to 1 to 2 to 5 to 20 (leaving the latitudes limits as they are), different numbers of the points are returned, even though all of the points fall into the polygon for all these values.

```
CREATE TABLE testing.tsttab
(
  lat real,
  lon real,
  tstpoint geography(Point,4326)
);

INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.1, 22.1, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(22.1 36.1)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.2, 22.2, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(22.2 36.2)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.3, 22.3, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(22.3 36.3)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.4, 22.4, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(22.4 36.4)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.5, 22.5, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(22.5 36.5)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.6, 23.1, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(23.1 36.6)'));
INSERT INTO testing.tsttab (lat, lon, tstpoint) values (36.7, 23.2, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(23.2 36.7)'));

select * from testing.tsttab
where st_intersects(
st_geogfromtext('POLYGON((2 35, 2 37, 40 37, 40 35, 2 35))'),tstpoint);
```

If I convert to GEOMETRY rather than GEOGRAPHY, it performs correctly.  Am I mis-using something?

Comment: Quick note, to find your exact version you can use SELECT postgis_version(); or to find your version and the versions of all of PostGIS's dependencies you can use SELECT postgis_full_version();

Answer (score 2):

What you think is the right answer may not be the right answer. You're using geography, so you're on the sphere now, not the plane.

http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/04/30/the-earth-is-not-flat-volume-2/